# How solve Pyhton getting invalid syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, operating-system

I'm trying typing

```
command = "aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[].{ instance_id: InstanceId, type: InstanceType, stats: State.Name, disks: BlockDeviceMappings[*].Ebs.VolumeId, p_ip: NetworkInterfaces[*].PrivateIpAddresses[].PrivateIpAddress, name: Tags[?Key == `Name`].Value, cpu: CpuOptions.CoreCount, platform: PlatformDetails}" > output.json"
os.system(command)
```

I got an error when debbuging. Is there anyone correct this syntax.

Comment: Either: a) replace outer `"` with `"""` (or `'`) or b) replace inner `"` with `\"`

Comment: You should add the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the double quotes:

```
command = "aws ec2 describe-instances --query \"Reservations[*].Instances[].{ instance_id: InstanceId, type: InstanceType, stats: State.Name, disks: BlockDeviceMappings[*].Ebs.VolumeId, p_ip: NetworkInterfaces[*].PrivateIpAddresses[].PrivateIpAddress, name: Tags[?Key == `Name`].Value, cpu: CpuOptions.CoreCount, platform: PlatformDetails}\" > out22.json"
os.system(command)
```